# I get this error about not enough video memory:tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError.But I have enough gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have multiple GPUs, some of them are in use：
Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 865 MB memory:  -> device: 0, n
Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 58104 MB memory:  -> device: 1,
Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 58234 MB memory:  -> device: 2,
There are eight of these in total
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:74 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16384,16384] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "COVID_GAN.py", line 313, in 
g_model = make_generator_model()
File "COVID_GAN.py", line 159, in make_generator_model
model.add(layers.Dense(128 * 128, use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
File "/mnt/data/ml/anaconda3/envs/tf_2.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 530, in _method_wrapper
result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/mnt/data/ml/anaconda3/envs/tf_2.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/mnt/data/ml/anaconda3/envs/tf_2.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 1833, in random_uniform
seed=self.make_legacy_seed())
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16384,16384] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]

Comment: I've tried specifying two of the graphics cards:gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

if gpus:
    visible_gpus = [gpus[3], gpus[4]]
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(visible_gpus, 'GPU')       But it's no use